Applications are not responding
Ubuntu's all applications (e.g. Files, LibreOffice, Brave, etc.) hang and freeze after 20 to 25 days of smoothly working "(app name) is not responding".
Also, it says "Internal error occurs in Ubuntu 24.04" What's the problem and how can I solve it? Is it a hardware or software related problem?
Note: If I reinstall again, then it works smoothly for like 20 to 25 days then again it begins to freeze and hang.
My laptop specifications are:
name: Hp
Ram: 4 GB
hdd: 1 TB
ssd: NO
Bought year: 2019
os: Ubuntu 24.04
swap memory:4 GB

Note: In Ubuntu 22.04 I faced this problem as well and updated to Ubuntu 24.04.

You're running with 4GB of memory and no SSD. This is an extremely "limited" system, which I would imagine giving performance issues. Maybe try a low-end flavor of Ubuntu, like Lubuntu or Xubuntu.
